# Is meteor.com made with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, web

I'm new to Meteor so I would like to know if I can look at [meteor.com](http://meteor.com) as an example of what can be done with Meteor or if it's made using other web technologies.

Since such website is more like a set of static pages rather than a single-page reactive web application, I think the answer is no but perhaps I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. Just open a developer console and type `Meteor` and you'll see.